# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been “select” but was “span”

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium webdriver code is

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='css3menu1']/li[3]/a/span"));
        Select se = new Select(element);
        String S =se.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
        System.out.println(S);
        List<WebElement> allOptions = se.getOptions();
        for (WebElement webElement : allOptions)
        {
            System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        }
        }
```

Here i want to print all options ..Please help me to get rid of this error and print all child options .

org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been “select” but was “span”

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments yet, but you're trying to create a select element from a WebElement of the wrong type. If you notice your xpath ends in span, that means the xpath is ultimately looking for a span element, not the select tag you want.

Try replacing this:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='css3menu1']/li[3]/a/span"));`

with this:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='css3menu1']/li[3]/a/select"));`

If that doesn't work, add the html around this selection so we can tell you the correct xpath you'll want to be using. Once you do I can help you get this sorted out.